# Using pipeline object to populate mail -to and -attachment

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, pipeline, email-attachments

First ever Powershell script so any advice or recommendations are appreciated. I'm parsing a .csv into smaller .csv's to send out information about servers to recipients and i'm running into a problem in my foreach. How do I get this to work?

One interesting thing is that in Send-MailMessage, -to should not accept pipeline objects, It still throws an error, but it still sends the emails. However the attachment will never send.

```
    #had to set this as a variable because @ was throwing splatting errors
    $Mail = "@Email.com"

    #Import csv and split information, exports UID.csv
    Import-csv C:\path\info.csv | Group-Object UID |    
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Export-csv "C:\path\$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
      }

    #Import file again to get unique list of UID and send mail with 
    #respective UID.csv

    Import-csv C:\path\info.csv | Group-Object UID |    
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.UID | Send-MailMessage -From "<Me@email.com>" -To "<$($_.Name)$Mail>" `
          -Attachments "C:\path\$($_.Name).csv" `
          -Subject "Testing" -Body "Please Ignore This" -Priority High `
          -SmtpServer smtp.server.com   
      }
```

Comment: assign the complex $Vars to intermediate $Vars and use those intermediate $Vars in your `Send-MailMessage` call. ///// also, backticks don't work at the START of a line ... only as the last thing at the END of  a line. [*grin*] they escape the "newline" ...

Comment: I've cleaned up the syntax errors and formatting in your question, because I assume they're only artifacts of posting and not your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

> in `Send-MailMessage`, `-to` should not accept pipeline objects

In principle it does, namely if the pipeline objects have a `.To` property (which is not the case for you).

However, with your current approach, you don't need pipeline input at all, given that you're supplying all input as *arguments*.

Additionally, your pipeline input is incorrect, because `$_.UID` sends `$null` through the pipeline, given that `$_` - a group-info object output by `Group-Object` - doesn't have a `.UID` property.

Using [delay-bind script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (`{ ... }`), you can simplify your command as follows, obviating the need for a `ForEach-Object` call:

```
Import-csv C:\path\info.csv | Group-Object UID |
  Send-MailMessage -From "<Me@email.com>" -To { "<$($_.Name)@Email.com>" } `
      -Attachments { "C:\path\$($_.Name).csv" } `
      -Subject "Testing" -Body "Please Ignore This" -Priority High `
      -SmtpServer smtp.server.com
```

In short, the script blocks passed to `-To` and `Attachments` are evaluated for each input object, and their output determines the parameter value in each iteration. In the script block, `$_` represents the pipeline object at hand, as usual.

Note that such delay-bind script blocks can only be used with parameters that are *designed to accept pipeline input* (irrespective of whether by value (whole object) or by a specific property's value).